# "Invalid arithmetic operator" error when checking hostname in Bash script

Tags: string, bash, comparison

I have a simple hostname check in a bash script:

```
if [[ `hostname` -eq "cps1214" ]]
then
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_21
fi
```

On our old SuSE 8 system this works fine. On our newer CentOS system this causes an error:

```
[[: dev.example.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator
(error token is ".example.com")
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is here. My understanding is that `-eq` is explicitly for string comparisons, `hostname` is clearly returning a string, and the right-hand side is also a string. Why is it complaining about arithmetic?

Comment: try "$(hostname)" == "cps1214" instead

Comment: I think you got Bash and Perl confused.  Bash `-eq` is specifically for numeric comparison, not strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `-eq` is not for string comparisons, but an arithmetic operator, as described in the bash documentation.

You can swap `-eq` with `=` or `==`, and you are fine.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html Also beware white space and note the number of brackets effect on the comparison.

Comment: the double-quotes used in examples I looked at led me to believe they were comparing as strings, but evidently double-quotes get sprayed everywhere in bash scripts. Changing to `==` has it working on both systems.